# Name Error., While solving Coupled Differential equation by 4th order Runge kutta algorithm

Tags: python

The code is to solve the Coupled differential equation by using Runge - Kutta algorithm the code looks fine but It is showing, Name error.

```
from math import *
x0=float(input('Enter the Iv for x '))
y0=float(input('Enter the corresponding y value'))
z0=float(input('Enter the corrsponding z value'))
print(x0,y0,z0)
A=input('dy/dx = f(x,y,z) =')
B=input('dz/dx = g(x,y,z) =')
def  f(x0,y0,z0):
  return(eval(A))
def g(x0,y0,z0):
  return(eval(B))
stp=float(input('Enter Step Size'))
z=int(input('Enter number of iteration'))
for i in range(1,z+1):
  k1=stp*f(x0,y0,z0)
  print(k1)
  l1=stp*g(x0,y0,z0)
  k2=stp*f(x0+.5*stp,y0+.5*k1,z0+.5*l1)
  l2=stp*g(x0+.5*stp,y0+.5*k1,z0+.5*l1)
  k3=stp*f(x0+.5*stp,y0+.5*k2,z0+.5*l2)
  l3=stp*g(x0+.5*stp,y0+.5*k2,z0+.5*l2)
  k4=stp*f(x0+stp,y0+k3,z0+l3)
  l4=stp*g(x0+stp,y0+k3,z0+l3)
  y1=y0+(k1+k4+2*(k2+k3))/6
  z1=z0+(l1+l4+2*(l2+l3))/6
  print('Value of y',i,"=",y1)
  print('Value of z',i,"=",z1)
  x0=x0+stp
  y0=y1
  z0=z0+stp
  z0=z1
```

[The image Shows The error that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH6ia.png)

Comment: I am using the following as f and g functions. dy/dx = f(x,y,z) = z
dz/dx = g(x,y,z) = -.5*y-7*z

Comment: your `eval` is looking for `y` based on your input but there is no `y` defined locally or globally, causing the name error

Comment: Please post your error message as code. Also, please take a look at our general guidelines regarding posting questions: [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`y` is not defined in your function scope for neither `f` nor `g` so when `eval(A)` and `eval(B)` are called, they cannot find `y` and `z` in the function space (nor the global) so if you rename the arguments for `f` and `g` to match how your input prompt presents them, they should be found by eval. That is,

```
def f(x, y, z):
    return eval(A)
```

or

```
def f(x0, y0, z0):
    return eval(A, {'x': x0, 'y': y0, 'z': z0})
```